# Dynamic text field

Tags: iphone, xcode, text, interface-builder, field

I am actually developing a view with a text field that I want to be dynamic.

Was dynamic means ?

It means, when you type something in it, there is a suggestion list populating beside the text filed. I have already coded that, and it works fine !

Representation of what I have right now :

[   text field   ] [ OK Button ]

[ suggestion 1 ]

[ suggestion 2 ]

[ suggestion 3 ]

Now what I want is to, when I select a suggestion in the list, add an item before the text field with for title the suggestion label, displaying like that :

< selected 1 > < selected 2 > [ text field ] [ OK ]

Has you imagine, the width of all these elements will be too large to fit in the screen. I want all that to be slidable from left to right with the finger.

What do you think about this ?

To you think it can be realized ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a `UIScrollView` with the size that you want. You then change its `contentSize` to the height/width that you want it to scroll. For example, you may want to create a `UIScrollView` that is 320px wide, but the `contentSize` is 700 px wide. This allows the view to scroll side to side. You will add your labels and such as subviews of this scrollview.

Comment: Thanks for this answer !

I'm trying this, I think it's a good solution, most boring is managing the placement of elements in relative position.

I'll make a best feedback when I'm done with this.